# Is it bad practice to pass null to a constructor args in PHP?

Tags: php, constructor

I just want to know if  it's a bad practise to pass null to constructor args in order to manage the non-override?

For example :

```
class Car
{
    private $brand;
    private $color;

    public function __construct($brand, $color=null) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a problem doing that

Comment: This would be called "optional argument" with default  value null. And it's not a problem at all.

Comment: It just means that the parameter is optional, that's no problem. Just make sure the rest of the code can handle `null` values.

Comment: Good that you're already preparing to handle colourless cars correctly... ;-P

Comment: PHP doesn't allow overloaded functions and allowing defaults to parameters is the way it compensates so setting a default to be `null` is fine.

Comment: what makes you think that it may be a bad practise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not. `null` is completely valid in PHP in terms of safeness (stuff like empty string or `"0"` or something like that is more potent to fail).

I think the correct question here is “is it bad to give default value to parameter of a contructor”, but to that question too, it is not.

My reasoning is that sometimes you want to imply default behaviour that would be used in most of the cases, and in some, say 5 % of cases, you need to alter behaviour of the object somehow, you’d want to be able to tell in the constructor that there is this kind of difference.

Sometimes, especially if the argument would make major change in the object, or if there is multiple values which are all used widely, it may more sense to use a method to set it. In you case, that method would be something like `$car->color("foo");`, and it would be implied to default to `null`.

Comment: "is it bad to give default value to parameter of a contructor" - you said "no" but it's entirely dependant on the scenario and code. Sometimes it is very bad, for me "most times" I prefer to force people to use a method explicitly. This avoids bugs and confusion for other devs "they don't pass some value did they mean to or want to use the default". But again, scenario dependant, sometimes default makes sense.